# Foreach loop per item fill document

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

I have got a list and I want to go through each item condition and insert it into a document. The issue is that I don’t know how to find an item and go through each condition till the item changes then start again.

```
Item    Condition       Total
Bag        New            3
Bag        Old            5
Jacket     New            2
Racket     New            1
Racket     old            3
Racket     unknown        8
```

This is what I do:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tracker.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {

                string template = @"C:\ document.pdf";
             string newFile = @"c:\"+ row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() +".pdf";
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
                AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

******************************************************************************

 // set values for fields
                        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "New")
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Condition", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Old")
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Condition2", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                        }

***************************************************************************************              

                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfStamper.Close();


            }
            else

            break;
        }
```

I want the code between the stars to fill the same document till row.cells[0].value changes then start the foreach again.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value of row.cells[0].value in a variable and compare it during each iteration of the foreach loop.

You also have to distinguish the first row from the rest, since only then a comparison of two values makes sense.

Example code:

```
string previousValue = null;
string currentValue = null;
bool firstRow = true;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tracker.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    currentValue = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    if (currentValue != null)
    {
            string template = @"C:\ document.pdf";
            string newFile = @"c:\"+ currentValue  +".pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;


            // Compare previous with current value
            if (!firstRow && previousValue != currentValue)
            {
                // Difference, start new document
                ....

            }
            else
            {
                // Same Value
            }

            // When row is handled, update previous with current value, and set firstRow to false

            previousValue = currentValue;
            firstRow = false;
...
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I am stuck on how to do it. Could you provide example please?

Comment: Or if it's easier can I sort my select query to show the conditions in different columns per item.